# OpenCV in Java, Junit 4 test case fails with Mat() object

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, opencv, junit

I'm developing an application within Java, so far it's gone well. I just began writing test cases and I'm having some issues in Eclipse with Junit 4 with openCV.

In particular, with the Mat() object.

```
Mat roiSrc;
```

Basically, Here is my test function to test a constructor for an object:

```
//expectedColor is a String value for the color name
    @Test
    public void test_Constructor(){
        System.out.println("Testing Sign Constructor");
        Sign test = new Sign();
        assertEquals(expectedColor,test.getColor());
    }
```

Here is the default sign constructor:

```
Sign() {
    roiSrc = new Mat();
    signText = "stop";
}
```

I have another default constructor to test loading of the images.

```
Sign() {
    roiSrc = Imgproc.imread(Sign.class.getResource("coolduck.jpg").getPath());
    signText = "stop";
}
```

The issue here, is both functions work just fine if I write an arbitrary program in java. However, When I got to create and run Junit tests, they come back with errors(No Failures, mind you).

Here's my Failure Trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:362)
    at com.add123.japr.Plate.<init>(Plate.java:48)
    at com.add123.japr.TestPlate.test_Constructor(TestPlate.java:15)
```

If I were to remove the line where I initialize the mat object in the constructor, it runs fine:
    Sign() {
        //roiSrc = Imgproc.imread(Sign.class.getResource("coolduck.jpg").getPath());
        signText = "stop";
    }

Anyone run into this before and solved it?

Comment: Maybe your run configuration is different for your junit test than your other programs? Are you forgetting to load the shared library in the junit test? How are you resolving the dlls or .sos?

Comment: Hey HughB, I just figured it out. Forgot to load the Native Libs for the test suite, but had loaded them on the draft program I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I forgot to include:

```
System.lostLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

in my test suite.

Comment: Should be loadLibrary :)